# Android Market Developer Console show no error report

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Market. Some users commented that it has FC and send a report via Android 2.2 reporting feature. However, it has been several days and I see nothing in the Application Error Reports of Developer Console. I try to reproduce the error myself and attempt report it, but still nothing is shown on the report page.

So I have the following questions:

1. Is there any things to do in an Android app to enable the reporting?
2. How long does it take to show the error on developer console after users report it?
3. Am I looking at wrong place for the reports?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use your own [Error Reporter](https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter) to report unhandled exceptions. The user will still have to click a button or something to send it to you.
2. It seems to be pretty immediate for me. Still user's have to choose and every device won't have the option to report.
3. In your dev console, on the market listings page, the 5th column will be links labeled **Errors**. If you have for example 2 new error reports, the link will be **Errors(2)**.

Comment: I expected the report to be immediate. But I see nothing when I tried to produce an error. And according to your description, I looked at the right place. :-)